# Run a .sql statement with keyword GO using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following

```
USE [TESTDB]
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Function1 (@input VARCHAR(250)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(250) 
AS 
BEGIN   
 --do work here
END

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Function2 (@input VARCHAR(250)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(250) 
AS BEGIN   
 --do work here
END
```

I tried to run this with my SQL connection in C#, but get the error:

> CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>     Must declare the scalar variable "@input ".

How can I run this in C#?

Comment: `GO` is not a keyword. It's a batch separator and it's not recognized by `SqlCommand`. What you need to do is split the text at GO (although it's a little more complicated than that) and use the command object to execute each part in sequence.

Comment: A regex pattern that closely approximates how SSMS splits your file into batches before running them is `(^GO\r?\n|\r?\nGO\r?\n|\r?\nGO$)`

Comment: so basically I could run them one at a time in different sql commands ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GO` is not a SQL concept; it literally doesn't exist in the syntax.

SSMS allows it by parsing the SQL, and recognizing `GO` (and `GO {integer}`) usage, and **splits your command into pieces**; it then issues those pieces separately one after the other as independent commands. It is entirely SSMS, not the SQL Server driver or the SQL Server database/server, that does this. `SqlClient` (the ADO.NET provider) does not have this functionality built in to mimic SSMS, so: you'd need to implement it in your own code. Or perhaps easier: just write your code as separate commands in the first place.