# Create/Alter procedure must be the first statement in the query batch

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to execute `SQL Script` file in my `bin` folder with code from Visual Studio, before now it was working fine when I was using `SQL Server 2012`, I recently installed `SQL server 2019` and I created the script using `SQL Server 2019`, when the application tries to execute the script I get the error

> create/alter procedure must be the first statement in the query batch

I went to a friend who has `SQL Server 2012` and created the script with his computer, it worked but when I create it with newer version I get the error, this is my code to read the script file :

```
public static string ReadDBFile(string path)
{
     string str;
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
     str = reader.ReadToEnd();
     str = str.Replace("GO", "");
     reader.Close();
     return str;
}
```

Here is where am executing the script file :

```
cmd.CommandText = ReadDBFile(Application.StartupPath + "/scriptfile.sql");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am sure this has to do with upgrade of `SQL Server`, any clue on how I could get this to work?

Comment: does your script contain `GO` by any chance? [`GO` is not a TSQL thing; it is only an SSMS thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482827/run-a-sql-statement-with-keyword-go-using-c/60484079#60484079); replacing `"GO"` with empty strings just... breaks things even more

Comment: The contents of your scriptfile.sql would be useful.

Comment: This SQL would not have been working "ok" on 2012. The error you're getting isn't a new one for 2019.

Comment: Just remove `str = str.Replace("GO", "");` line from your code, it's breaking things...

Comment: You removed the `GO` batch terminator so the script isn't valid if there are statements before or after the `CREATE VIEW`. You need to either run the script with SQLCMD or execute the script in the app code using an SMO method that recognizes batch terminators.

Comment: Is replacing 'GO' with empty  empty string a problem? @Ben the script file is large that why i didnt share it, all the script is doing is creating tables and stored procedures

Comment: Yes, replacing `GO` with an empty string is problematic - a) they're being used to tell client tools where to split the script into batches and b) the letters `GO` don't necessarily *just* appear in your "large script" as the batch separator. I.e. if you have a column called `BINGO`, anything touching that column in your script is now looking for a column called `BIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the DB file, replace `\r\n` with `\n`, split* it on the string `"\nGO\n"` and loop the resulting array executing the statements therein one by one

Something more like:

```
public static string ExecBatchSql(string path)
{
    string f = File.ReadAllText(path).Replace("\r\n", "\n");
    string fs = f.Split(new[]{"\nGO\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach(string cmd in fs){

      SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand(cmd, connStr);
      c.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

- note: check your file to ensure that GO appears on a line by itself with no leading or trailing spaces. If it does, adjust your split to be a bit smarter (may have to use regex)

Comment: The client tools ignore `GO` if it appears inside a (multi-line) string literal or comment, even when it's the only thing appearing on a line by itself. Good luck writing that regex!

Comment: Sorry for my late feedback, I lost power, you guys are awesome, everything works fine now thanks a lot.